# How to prevent reenter in node

Tags: node.js

How to prevent re-entering an operation? For example:

```
var updateValue = function(cb) {
  readValFromDB(function(err, val) {
    if (err) { /* ... */ }

    val = val + 1;
    saveValToDB(function(err2, val) {
      if (err2) { /* ... */ }

      cb();
    });
  });
};

for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
  updateValue(function() {

  });
}
```

If there is a value in a field in the database.  The initial value is 0; After 100 times update, I hope the value in database will become 100.

while in node, after 100 times update, the value in database will be 1, 2, 3 or other random value. Because, `readValFromDB()` could have been executed many times before the first `saveValToDB()` is called.  In other words, there is no serialization for this.

Is there a way in node to make sure the value could be 100 after 100 times update?

Comment: Definitely such a thing is not going to work in Node.js; Node is a non blocking language, which means it does not wait to finish the operations; you need to use async.each or async.map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is a race condition. The value is being read and written all at the same time.

You can do all the writes sequentially (see [async#eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries)).

Usually a better solution is to do the increment on the database server. See mongodb [$inc operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and redis [INCR operator](http://redis.io/commands/INCR) as examples of an *atomic increment*.